# Error: 1105 in sql server

Tags: sql-server-2012-express

I'm using `SOL server 2012` as database server.
Right now `mdf` file size is around `10 GB`.
When ever I'm doing any transaction into this database `sql server` troughs bellow error

> Error Number : 1105 Error Message :Could not allocate space for object  dbo.tblsdr . PK_*tblsdr*_3213E83F0AD2A005  in database  hwbsssdr  because the  PRIMARY  filegroup is full. 
>   Create disk space by deleting unneeded files, dropping objects in the filegroup, adding additional files to the filegroup, or setting autogrowth on for existing files in the file-group.

There is almost `400 GB` of free space is available on my disc.
Can any one tell me what is the issue and how can i solve that.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Express edition of SQL Server 2012, there is a limitations of 10GB per database, so this is your problem.

By the way, problem doesn't need necessarily to be with disk that is running out.

Also, if you have database with set up MAXSIZE to specific value, and if database reach that value every next transaction will report error from your question.

So, if you are sure that you have enough disk space for next transactions, check MAXSIZE property of your database executing next code:

```
use master;
go

exec sp_helpdb [YourDatabase]
```

If you want to change MAXSIZE database property, you can do this with next code:

```
alter database [YourDatabase]
modify file
(
    name = 'YourDatabaseFile',
    maxsize = X MB 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Explanation**

```
The specified filegroup has run out of free space.
```

**Action**

```
To gain more space, you can free disk space on any disk drive containing a file in the full filegroup, allowing files in the group to grow. Or you can gain space using a data file with the specified database.
```

**Freeing disk space**

```
 You can free disk space on your local drive or on another disk drive. To free disk space on another drive:
    Move the data files in the filegroup with an insufficient amount of free disk space to a different disk drive.
    Detach the database by executing sp_detach_db.
    Attach the database by executing sp_attach_db, pointing to the moved files.
```

**Using a data file**

```
 Another solution is to add a data file to the specified database using the ADD FILE clause of the ALTER DATABASE statement. Or you can enlarge the data file by using the MODIFY FILE clause of the ALTER DATABASE statement, specifying the SIZE and MAXSIZE syntax.
```

Comment: I have 2 drives on my system with the size of 500 GB each.
And also C have 300 GB of free space and other one have 200 GB of free space.I think there is sufficient space for database files.